# JS Query iFrame Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to load a modal window with an iFrame inside. The iFrame url varies according one  parameter from page to page.

For instance, the url varies according to term1/term2 http://www.example.com/**term1** http://www.example.com/**term2**

Right now, I have a js code like this:

```
jQuery('.eModal-1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#eModal-1 iframe').attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    jQuery('#eModal-1').emodal('open');
});
```

And am opening the modal window like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/term1" class="eModal-1">Click</a>
```

Within the modal I have:

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting a fixed URL instead of "jQuery(this).attr('href')" to ensure that this is not part of the problem.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, what do you want to do?

Comment: @numX Thanks. I want to open a modal window containing an iFrame. The iFrame is the same URL on each page apart from one number in the URL. So I want to save that number as a field of meta data and adjust the iFrame URL according to it.

Comment: so could you concatenate this number to the url as part of the querystring? 
    url2 = url + number;    then set the src to the variable url2

Comment: @numX Yes, how would that look in my query? Thanks!

Comment: var src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
var src2 = src.concat("\term1"); 
 jQuery('#eModal-1 iframe').attr('src', src2);